# Base class for Multiple Projects (MS Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inheritance

What would be the best way to have a base class and 2 subclasses that run as 2 different projects in the same solution file that use that base class using Microsoft Visual Studio for C++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Base Class for multiple classes in different projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30192323/base-class-for-multiple-classes-in-different-projects)

Comment: I saw that answer, but I was wondering if there was a way around having to create a static library.

Comment: You could refer to Microsoft Docs about [how to create and use a static library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Yeah--I ended up using that resource. Thanks @Barrnet Chou and @PajLe!